# Find the length of CX

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I found this question on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/DrPMaths/status/1529109155612659718/photo/1)

[image]

My Attempt:

I marked the circumcenter of the circle as O and drew radii $OA, OB, OC$ and with some angle chasing, I found the angles marked in the diagram attached below.

As that didn't work drew line OX. That didn't work either.

[image]

I can easily find the length of $CX$ using trigonometry but I like to solve this kind of geometry problem with elementary knowledge.

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem using Elementary geometry?

Thank you

Comment: If you did solve the problem with trigonometry then you know that answer is expressed in terms of $\sin 20^\circ$, which is root of cubic equation. One can find first $r$ and then $CX$ as roots of algebraic equations, but this solution is much harder than just writing expression with $\sin 20^\circ$.

Comment: There is no simple solution without using trigonometry because answer is non-rational root of equation $3x^6-18900x^4+780000x^2-1000000=0$. Answer can be expressed in radicals or in trigonometric functions. Second representation is mush simpler for this case.

Comment: Thank you very much @IvanKaznacheyeu.